# How to resolve irritating purple lines in NetBeans 7.3.1?

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete

In `NetBeans 7.3.1` when I try to create an anonymous class and override it's method with auto-completion the method is surrounded by a irritating purple line. I can't get rid of that purple line. There is one way though by selecting the method text and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. But it is not an elegant way.

I tried googling and nothing came up.

For those who want to visualize

[image]

Comment: Press Enter. After new Runnable() is just implemented, the cursor is at the lowest purple block, between the } and ). When you then press Enter, the cursor moves 2 spaces and is now behind the semicolon and the purple lines will disappear.

Comment: D'oh it was always there. Thanks problem resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

After `new Runnable()` is just implemented, the cursor is at the lowest purple block, between the `}` and `)`. When you then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the cursor moves 2 spaces and is now behind the semicolon and the purple lines will disappear.